# Divergent alternating series with subsequences approaching to $+\infty,-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

I'd like to discuss the following problem,

Given the following series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (e^{n\cdot cos(\pi n)} - n)$$

discuss the convergence,divergence...

The question is how to approach the general method when I discover  there are two subsequences that respectively have two different limits :

Noticing that $n \cdot cos(\pi n) = n \cdot (-1)^{n}$ we can see that if $n$ is even $a_{n} = e^{n} - n$, if odd $a_{n} = \frac{1}{e^{n}} - n $

So we found two subsequences,the first one positive, the second one negative, that respectively go to $+\infty,-\infty$.

Is there a general approach to formalise the fact that $a_{2n} $ is growing to $+\infty$ much faster than $a_{2n+1}$ is decreasing to $-\infty$ and thus the series is diverging to $+\infty$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I read your question wrongly and thought you were discussing about sequence earlier.

Since
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{2n}-(2n)+\frac1{e^{2n-1}}-(2n-1)=+\infty$$

The series go to $+\infty$.